# Getting Error: TypeError: Cannot call method "getThreads" of null. (line 3, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script

You must be aware of this SMS notification of emails received trick/app at this link.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/gmail_filter_sms

As I follow the steps mentioned at above link and when I copy and paste the code thereon into script editor I get the following error:

TypeError: Cannot call method "getThreads" of null. (line 3, file "Code")

What to do now, Do you have any solution to this issue ?

Please help

Regards,
Vaibhav,
PS: Please tell me the steps to resolve the issue as I'm novice to this programming field.

Answer (score 0):

What label name are you using? If you are using the code as is, then the label name should be `'Send text'`. Make sure this is not a nested label in your Gmail. If it is nested then replace it in code as `'ParentLabel/ChildLabel'`. I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Hey thank for your reply. I'm using the same label name and it's not a nested label. Please help. still getting the same error. Is there a problem with code or what ?